# Crear procedure con parametros de entrada, e insertar posteriormente en BD tras una validación

Tags: mysql

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy tratando de crear un procedimiento que reciba parámetros de entrada y compruebre si los datos existen o no, para poder insertar en una tabla u otra. 
He probado de diferentes maneras y no consigo dar con el error que aparece en la sintaxis, de la declaración.

Por favor necesito ayuda.

Mil gracias de antemano.

/*A continuación muestro el código del procedimiento*/

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMensaje(IN pNOMBRE varchar(50), IN pTLFN varchar(9), IN pEMAIL varchar(50), IN pASN varchar(15), IN pMSG varchar(500))

BEGIN

    /*declaro valiable*/
    DECLARE vIDCLI int;

/*ESTAS OPCIONES TAMBIÉN HE PROBADO*/
/*SET vIDCLI = (select id_cliente from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL);*/
/*select id_cliente into vIDCLI from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL;*/

/* DECLARE vAUX varchar(50)*/ 
/* SET vAUX = (select email from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL);*/
/* select email into vAUX from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL; */

/* IF (vAUX <=> NULL) THEN  */

    /*compruebo si existe el parámetro pEMAIL*/
    IF EXISTS (select id_cliente from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL) THEN

    /*recupero el ID y lo asigno a la variable*/
    select id_cliente into vIDCLI from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL;

        /*inserto en BD tabla mensaje*/
        INSERT INTO `tb_msg`(`asn`, `msg`, `id_cli`) VALUES ('pASN','pMSG','vIDCLI');

    ELSE
        /*inserto nuevo cliente*/
        INSERT INTO `tb_cliente`(`nombre`, `tlfn`, `email`) 
                        VALUES ('pNOMBRE','pTLFN','pEMAIL');

        /*recupero new IdCli*/
        SET vIDCLI = (select id_cliente from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL);

        /*insert en la tabla mensaje*/
        INSERT INTO `tb_msg`(`asn`, `msg`, `id_cli`) VALUES ('pASN','pMSG',vIDCLI);
    END IF;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

MySQL ha dicho:

> 1064 -  Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'IF EXISTS (select id_cliente from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL) THEN' en la linea 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad puedes verificar si el email existe dentro del mismo procedimiento almacenado, lo hice con una funcion porque supuse que dentro de tu desarrollo necesitaras comprobar la existencia de un email en diferentes procedimientos, entonces la funcion "existe_EMAIL" te permitira reutilizarla ésta parte del codigo.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMensaje(
    IN pNOMBRE varchar(50), 
    IN pTLFN varchar(9), 
    IN pEMAIL varchar(50), 
    IN pASN varchar(15), 
    IN pMSG varchar(500))

BEGIN

/*declaro valiable*/
DECLARE vIDCLI INT DEFAULT 0;

/*compruebo si existe el parámetro pEMAIL*/
IF `existe_EMAIL`(pEMAIL) THEN

    /*recupero el ID y lo asigno a la variable*/
    select id_cliente into vIDCLI from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL;

    /*inserto en BD tabla mensaje*/
    INSERT INTO `tb_msg`(`asn`, `msg`, `id_cli`) VALUES (pASN, pMSG, vIDCLI);

ELSE
    /*inserto nuevo cliente*/
    INSERT INTO `tb_cliente`(`nombre`, `tlfn`, `email`) 
                    VALUES (`pNOMBRE`, `pTLFN`, `pEMAIL`);

    /*recupero new IdCli*/
    /*SET vIDCLI = (select id_cliente from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL); CODIGO INEFICIENTE*/ 
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO vIDCLI; /* CORRECTO */

    /*insert en la tabla mensaje*/
    INSERT INTO `tb_msg`(`asn`, `msg`, `id_cli`) VALUES (`pASN`,`pMSG`, vIDCLI);
END IF;
END; //

DELIMITER ;



/* Funcion que verifica si un email existe en la tabla tb_cliente */
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `existe_EMAIL`(pEMAIL VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN

    DECLARE existe boolean DEFAULT FALSE;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT email FROM tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL) THEN
        SET existe = TRUE;
    END IF;

RETURN existe;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Gustavo Mil gracias, por tu ayuda!! Esto significa que no puedo verificar si existe el EMAIL dentro del mismo procedimiento, es necesario realizar la validación a parte. Muchísimas gracias de nuevo Gustavo +1

Comment: En realidad puedes verificar si el email existe dentro del mismo procedimiento almacenado, lo hice con una funcion porque supuse que dentro de tu desarrollo necesitaras comprobar la existencia de un email en diferentes procedimientos, entonces la funcion "existe_EMAIL" te permitira reutilizarla ésta parte del codigo.

Comment: @GustavoGeronimoFernandez excelente tu contribución Gustavo, solo recuerda siempre agregar una explicación y no solo agregar código en las respuestas, esto para que sea de ayuda a todos los miembros de la comunidad, revisa [answer|, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar la condición `select if,  SELECT IF(500<1000, "YES", "NO");`

`IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

De igual manera, prueba agregar el `begin` entre el `if exist` y el `select` que retornas.

Otra forma sería que el `select` que haces de `id cliente` lo guardes en una variable y uses la función `ISNULL` de `mysql` para chequear.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, pero he añadido otras opciones que he probado previamente, y siguen dando error.

A lo que me comentas select if (.....) no entiendo exactamente a que te refieres.

Un saludo,

Comment: es una funcion investigala select if y abajo te puse como se usaria

Comment: Gracias Gonzalo, en esta vez, esta función no es apropiada para para la condición que necesito, pero la tendré en cuenta en otras ocasiones venideras. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y dedicación. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Parece un problema de delimitadores. Cambia `DELIMITER ;` por `DELIMITER //` y asegúrate de tener todas las líneas con sus respectivos `;` excepto el final que está bien: `END; //`

Comment: Hola Javi, Agradezco tu respuesta, Pero he probado con diferentes delimitadores, y las líneas de código están todas bien cerradas. Si pudieras copiar el fragmento de código que he subido y pegarlo en phpmyadmin, podrías comprobar como el error salta antes de llegar al limitador. se atasca en la linea que aparece en el error.

Comment: Prueba en este fiddle y verás como te da un error que desaparece cuando cambias de delimitador en el desplegable y seleccionas //: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc6c5

Comment: Seguramente necesites añadir una línea antes del create procedure tal y como la que tienes al final pero con DELIMITER //

Comment: NO, me sigue sin funcionar, ni con delimitador ni sin él. Es un error muy extraño la verdad, no entiendo que es lo que está ocurriendo y ya llevo unos días con él, he intentado en lugar de procedimiento una función, y 3/4 partes de lo mismo... Muchas gracias por tu esfuerzo y dedicación, pero sigo igual -<de todas formas comentarte también, que en el link que me indicas me da un error de  DDL y DML que no están permitidas-